# Add GAC assembly to Visual Studio 2010 'Add Reference' dialog

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, .net-assembly

I realize that my assembly does not have anything to do with being in the GAC for this question but that is how everyone is referencing this.  The assembly in question is in the GAC though.

So I have a code library I want to list in the 'add references' dialog in visual studio.  The assemblies there are in directories that are specified in the registry.  An example is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\MyAssemblies]@="C:\\MyAssemblies"
```

(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149)

I have also tried many of the suggestions listed on here and around the web but nothing works.  I am also restarting visual studio after editing the registry.  The assembly is signed and is included int he GAC just fine. It is compiled for .NET 3.5 (not .NET 3.5 Client Profile).

Does anyone have any suggestions, or tips on what worked for them?  Just to reiterate I have tried systematically adding entries in about 10 places in the GAC.  Unused entries are removed when I'm done in order to not cause conflicts.

The example above references HKCU but I have also put entries under HKLM.

Comment: I doubt you have not restarted the your machine?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar yes I tried rebooting and no results.

Comment: I was able to add my assemblies to an existing .NET assembly folder and they showed up fine: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 - My issue seems to be adding my own registry keys to scan my libraries directory in %programfiles%

Answer (score 1):

Phew! Ok so there are many places that VS will search for assemblies.  For some reason when I made entries to the above registry key it simply would not pick up my defined paths.  Instead the place I needed to add a key was in:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx
```

Also note that the .NET version - this allows you to target the different .net versions.

If you are having similar issues I recommend reading this article fully:
https://msmvps.com/blogs/p3net/pages/integrating-gac-assemblies-with-visual-studio.aspx